# dynamically set row number depending on its position

Tags: javascript

I have a list of `sections` having each one premade `div` and a `button` to dynamically create new divs underneath. The divs are always created at the end of the section they are in and should be numbered after their position in the row instead of their order of creation.

```
<section id="section1"><div class="premade">1</div></section>
<button onclick="addRow(1)">Create new</button>
<section id="section2"><div class="premade">2</div></section>
<button onclick="addRow(2)">Create new</button>
```

I'm stuck trying to set each number dynamically. When I create a new div, it should get its number depending on the section I choose to create it in and the number of divs this section already contains plus the number of divs the previous sections have. And not like I did :

```
section.innerHTML += '<div class="created"> ' + parseInt(index + R) + '</div>'
R += 1;
```

The code I wrote gets the right number when I create new divs from first to last sections, but it fails when I go back to a previous section to create a new one as it doesn't know the number of existing divs the sections already have. The number the divs positioned after the new one have should also be changed to match their new position in the row. I'm stuck trying to find the proper syntax in javascript. Any idea of how I might do that ?

Thanks for your help

My fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/balleronde/8bx98a0r/

Comment: Presuming *index* is a string, then `parseInt(index + R)` would need to be `parseInt(index) + R`, but perhaps it's not needed anyway. ;-)

Comment: In javascript the '+' in 'parseInt(index) + R' would associate the numbers like 1 + 1 = 11, instead of doing math 1+1 = 2.Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: Using `parseInt(index + R)` guarantees that if either is a string, then `1 + 1` will be `11`. Each value must be converted to a number first, I assumed that *R* would be initialised to a number and therefore doesn't need conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a separate R variable(counter) for each section, if I grasped what you really meant.

lets say R1 is the counter for top most section, R2 is the counter for 2nd top most section, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Here is where I got using your suggestion :https://jsfiddle.net/balleronde/Loj0xyvk/2/ I still can't figure how to add the properties of the object to the next ones so that they keep track of the previous ones values

Comment: hi Nora, which "previous ones values"? could you be more specific. thanks.  edit: initialize R1 = 1, R2 = 2, R3 = 3, so on?

Comment: make another variable attached to each section for a total number so far. so everytime you make a new square, just add that additional number to the totalNumber1(for section 1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer techfang. I'm still struggling with my code though. Simply initializing R1 = 1, R2 = 2, R3 = 3 etc won't actually solve my problem because no matter how many squares I add in section1, the new squares in section2 will still start their count at number 3 (value of R2 + 1) instead of keeping track of R1 value and then adding +1.

Comment: My best bet was to try keeping track of the number of squares in each section. Based on your suggestion I tried to define my variables like this : R1 = 1, R2 = R1 +1, R3 = R2 +1, etc. These definitions work when the page loads (hurrah!) but they don't change when I add new squares. It's like they're stuck on the value defined at page load instead of changing dynamically. I probably didn't write this code properly ? Here is what I tried : https://jsfiddle.net/balleronde/h7hm9zp4/2/

Comment: Ok so I don't know exactly how or why, but just when I was about to give up I came out with a working solution to this problem :-D I still need to find a way to update each square's inner HTML to make it match their new number and I'm done ! Thank you again for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You should split "views" from "data".

For instance, you might track your data as a list or array of objects `[{section: "section1", id:1},{section: "section2", id:2}]` and "build" your HTML from that data.

THen you would only need to change the array data, (edit, insert or delete an object), and call a function to "rebuild" your view from the new object list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using an object to store the number of divs for each sections seems to be the correct way to go, as it allows me to dynamically use the index of the button clicked to browse the object properties. I'm still struggling with the syntax though... I tried to add the values of the object properties, each one being the sum of the previous ones, but I'm obviously doing it wrong. Any hint of what the correct syntax would be ? Sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a global R value to assign to new sections, as that will be updated to R+1 no matter where the new section is.

What you should do is try to find the "R" value after each button click. and update all the sections blow the newly created one.

P.S. Use jQuery make it easier.